# RichTextBox ScrollToCaret crashes app sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I add text to a richtextbox. Sometimes It crashes and this is the error I get: [image: RTB error]

```
        try{

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {

                log_window.richTextBox1.SuspendLayout();
                log_window.richTextBox1.Text += whatever + text + nner;         
                log_window.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = log_window.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                log_window.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();            
                log_window.richTextBox1.ResumeLayout();     

            });     
        }
        catch/*(Exception Ex)*/
        {

        }
```

This one also fails with the same error:

```
        try{

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {

                log_window.richTextBox1.SuspendLayout();
                log_window.richTextBox1.Text += whatever + text + nner;         
                log_window.richTextBox1.ResumeLayout();     
                log_window.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = log_window.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                log_window.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();                                    

            });     
        }
        catch/*(Exception Ex)*/
        {

        }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should post the exact error instead of the screenshot.

Comment: Don't you see the errno in the screenshot or what's the pb.?

Comment: The problem is that not everyone chooses to display images in their browser so you are limiting your audience, on top of that it is *much* harder to read compared to the actual text, and less informative as you can even see yourself that information is cropped.

Comment: It's hard to replicate , I only get it sometimes I did the printscreen and forgot to copy the text. thanks anyway, you're right!

Comment: Normally problems that are hard to reproduce are also going to be hard for others to help you im afraid, at a glance, I would imagine its something related to the invoking but that could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log_window.richTextBox1.Focus();

before SelectionStart solved my problem.